# Big-O: n^2 = Ω(n log n)?

Tags: time, time-complexity, big-o

Would Ω(n log n) be the same as saying n^2?

Extra: Can someone please explain to me clearly what big O, Θ and Ω means illustratively?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not, it is Omega, which says "It is asymptotically same or lower".

In "asymptoticall" equations, it is same as `n^2 >= n log n`

---

Extra :

**Standard equations** || **Text representation** || **Asymptotically equations**

```
f(x) = O(g(x)) || g(x) is asymptotically same or higher as f(x) || f(x) <= g(x)
f(x) = Θ(g(x)) || g(x) is asymptotically same as f(x) || f(x) = g(x)
f(x) = Ω(g(x)) || g(x) is asymptotically same or lower as (fx) || f(x) >= O(g(x))
```

PS: Note also that if `f(x) = O(g(x))` it also means that `g(x) = Ω(f(x))`, which is similar to if `f(x) <= g(x)` then `g(x) >= f(x)`

Answer (score 0):

`n^2 = Ω(n log n)` is not equality, but relation between these functions.
You can read about it and see examples [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/algorithms/asymptotic-notation/a/big-big-theta-notation).